# mongoid / mongodb - replicating/copy records

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am building a cms where the site and pages are stored within mongo. I need to be able to create a new site using another site as a template.

For example:

```
   Site A - news page and home page
```

Create a new site selecting site A as a template, this selects site A and then makes copies of each page site A owns and saves them under Site B

The result

```
   Site A - news page and home page 
   Site B - news page and home page
```

Site B will be able to then use site A as a starting point to build there new site.

I am new to Mongo/mongoid so really would like some pointers about the best way to approach this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to organise the data is to use collections with the site ID as the namespace, giving you collections like:

```
site_a.pages
site_a.news
site_a.users
site_b.pages
site_b.news
site_b.users
```

To create a new site from an existing one, you would copy the relevant collections (possibly excluding `.users` for example), changing the namespace. That is, copy `site_a.pages` to `site_c.pages`. [In the shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Developer+FAQ#DeveloperFAQ-HowdoIcopyallobjectsfromonedatabasecollectiontoanother%3F):

```
db.site_a.pages.find().forEach( function(x){db.site_c.pages.insert(x)} );
```

Note that `site_a` is not a database name, but [the namespace of a collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Collections).

There is a limit to the number of collections you can have in a database that might be a problem if you're hosting the CMS in the cloud for many customers. You could get around this by having different databases for different customers. You should read the [documentation on this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections) for more details.

Another way to do this is to put the site ID in each document and always filter for this in your queries. Then you would only have a few collections, for example:

```
pages
news
users
```

With the documents in those collections having a `site_id` field:

```
{
    "site_id": "site_a",
    "page_title": "Homepage",
    ...
}
```

The copying would be similar to above (but with filters and updating the `site_id` field in the function). I think namespaces for collections is a neater approach however.